# Can't delete image in contenteditable div on Android

Tags: android, webview, contenteditable, richtext

I am building a rich text editor in android. To do so, I am using a `webView` with a `contentEditable div.`

To add styles, I invoke `JavaScript`. This all works fine, except when I invoke JavaScript to insert either an image or a horizontal rule. When I use JavaScript to insert these things, if I then try to press the back button to delete either the image or the horizontal rule, it doesn't work.

Oddly enough, if I first enter any other character, and then insert the image or horizontal rule, I can delete the image/horizontal rule just fine, but cannot delete the character I entered immediately before the image/horizontal rule.

I've tried printing out the HTML in every state, checking the selection/range, etc, and can't seem to find anything that's different about the state that might explain why I can't delete the image, etc.

Comment: Could you try to provide us some input on how you coded both the HTML+Javascript and the Android Java code (I'm guessing the WebChromeClient)?

Comment: You're not providing enough information to be very precise, I'd hazard a guess that as you have HTML behind the scenes your backspace actually deletes the last part of the tag (which is enoguh to stop it displaying) and the reason you can't delete what's visually before the item is that further presses of backspace delete more of the tag. E.. <hr/> is displayed, thenbackspace and you have <hr/ so nothing is displayed...

Comment: Show some JS code, show some sample div content (http://stackoverflow.com/questions/how-to-ask)
You should implement and add an event listener to the div which knows how to delete a complete HTML element, e.g. when pressing Backspace or Delete.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14560344/android-backspace-in-webview-baseinputconnection

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14560344/android-backspace-in-webview-baseinputconnection

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14560344/android-backspace-in-webview-baseinputconnection

Answer (score 1):

[Android: Backspace in WebView/BaseInputConnection](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14560344/android-backspace-in-webview-baseinputconnection)

Subclass Webview and override the method as shown by this guy's question.

On some phones, only the guy's question will satisfy the requirements.  The link's answer will complete the code for compatibility with other phones.  Though, you subclass a InputConnectionWrapper.  not inputconnection.  and then return that wrapper within your custom webview.

Just a FYI, this link has a much more detailed explanation of the situation, however I tried quickly implementing their ideas and it didn't work.  Maybe too complicated for my purposes.  The reason I tried their solution instead of what I mentioned above is because the solution I mentioned above causes the voice-to-text function to not work correctly.
[Android - cannot capture backspace/delete press in soft. keyboard](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18581636/android-cannot-capture-backspace-delete-press-in-soft-keyboard/19980975#19980975)

Answer (score 0):

I have implemented a richTextEditor using `WebView` and `JavaScript`.

I had no problem in inserting/deleting image that I have added to
content editable html page. Code that I have used for inserting image is

```
String exeSucess = "document.execCommand('insertHtml', false,'<img src=\""
        + selectedImagePath + "\" height=auto width=200 ></img>');";
   //Then code for executing this javascript.
```

Thanks.

Comment: Do you not have any issues deleting the image with the cursor? I have all sorts of problems doing that. I tried overriding the deleteSurroundingText method, which many other threads on stackoverflow suggest, but didn't really have any luck. When overriding that, it ruined all the autocomplete state, so would insert or delete random characters frequently -- obviously a big issue.

Comment: I was able to insert image by executing above javascript and also able to delete it by pressing backpress button in SoftKeyboard. Working on nexus,htc one v but in very low end devices it has some stuck issues.

Answer (score -1):

```
<div contenteditable="true"></div>
```

I use this to do a rich editor in a webview

Then override method `TapInputConnection` in Webview

```
@Override
public InputConnection onCreateInputConnection(EditorInfo outAttrs) {
    return new TapInputConnection(super.onCreateInputConnection(outAttrs));
}



class TapInputConnection implements InputConnection {

    private InputConnection mConnection;


    public TapInputConnection(InputConnection conn){
        this.mConnection = conn;
    }

    @Override
    public CharSequence getTextBeforeCursor(int n, int flags) {
        return mConnection.getTextBeforeCursor(n, flags);
    }

    @Override
    public CharSequence getTextAfterCursor(int n, int flags) {
        return mConnection.getTextAfterCursor(n, flags);
    }

    @Override
    public CharSequence getSelectedText(int flags) {
        return mConnection.getSelectedText(flags);
    }

    @Override
    public int getCursorCapsMode(int reqModes) {
        return mConnection.getCursorCapsMode(reqModes);
    }

    @Override
    public ExtractedText getExtractedText(ExtractedTextRequest request, int flags) {
        return mConnection.getExtractedText(request, flags);
    }

    @Override
    public boolean deleteSurroundingText(int beforeLength, int afterLength) {
        return mConnection.deleteSurroundingText(beforeLength, afterLength);
    }

    @Override
    public boolean setComposingText(CharSequence text, int newCursorPosition) {
        return mConnection.setComposingText(text, newCursorPosition);
    }

    @Override
    public boolean setComposingRegion(int start, int end) {
        return mConnection.setComposingRegion(start, end);
    }

    @Override
    public boolean finishComposingText() {
        return mConnection.finishComposingText();
    }

    @Override
    public boolean commitText(CharSequence text, int newCursorPosition) {
        return mConnection.commitText(text, newCursorPosition );
    }

    @Override
    public boolean commitCompletion(CompletionInfo text) {
        return mConnection.commitCompletion(text);
    }

    @Override
    public boolean commitCorrection(CorrectionInfo correctionInfo) {
        return mConnection.commitCorrection(correctionInfo);
    }

    @Override
    public boolean setSelection(int start, int end) {
        return mConnection.setSelection(start, end);
    }

    @Override
    public boolean performEditorAction(int editorAction) {
        return mConnection.performEditorAction(editorAction);
    }

    @Override
    public boolean performContextMenuAction(int id) {
        return mConnection.performContextMenuAction(id);
    }

    @Override
    public boolean beginBatchEdit() {
        return mConnection.beginBatchEdit();
    }

    @Override
    public boolean endBatchEdit() {
        return mConnection.endBatchEdit();
    }

    @Override
    public boolean sendKeyEvent(KeyEvent event) {
        if (event.getKeyCode() == KeyEvent.KEYCODE_DEL) {
            if (event.getAction() == KeyEvent.ACTION_UP) {
                delete();
            }
            return true;
        }
        return mConnection.sendKeyEvent(event);
    }

    @Override
    public boolean clearMetaKeyStates(int states) {
        return false;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean reportFullscreenMode(boolean enabled) {
        return mConnection.reportFullscreenMode(enabled);
    }

    @Override
    public boolean performPrivateCommand(String action, Bundle data) {
        return mConnection.performPrivateCommand(action, data);
    }

    @TargetApi(Build.VERSION_CODES.LOLLIPOP)
    @Override
    public boolean requestCursorUpdates(int cursorUpdateMode) {
        return mConnection.requestCursorUpdates(cursorUpdateMode);
    }
}
```

You have realized that I override `sendKeyEvent` and I deal with `Delete` Key by myself

This is the `delete()` function;

```
public void delete(){
  loadurl("javascript:document.execCommand('delete', false, null);");
}
```

Comment: Please, please, please change your formatting. Thank you.