# Android Webview Strategy For Deleting Images Causing Speech-To-Text to Fail

Tags: android, webview, android-inputtype

Problem: 
[Can't delete image in contenteditable div on Android](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18093067/cant-delete-image-in-contenteditable-div-on-android/24591285#24591285)

Only known solution at the moment:
[Android: Backspace in WebView/BaseInputConnection](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14560344/android-backspace-in-webview-baseinputconnection)

Problem with solution:
Setting:  creating a BaseInputConnection using the regular constructor seems to disable speech to text from functioning correctly.  as opposed to using WebView.onCreateInputConnection(EditorInfo) to generate an InputConnection.

any ideas how to remedy this?

Comment: You asked for help on this. I am sorry, but I do not do much complex with `WebView` and have never touched `InputConnection` in my life.

Answer (score 1):

I had the same issue also with text completion using SwiftKey. In order to fix it you must remember some things:

- you must extend BaseInputConnection and *wrap* the original webview's InputConnection
- don't use InputConnectionWrapper as it will cause other problems
- you need to subclass a second method: commitText

  ```
  public boolean commitText(CharSequence text, int newCursorPosition) {

      if (android.os.Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= android.os.Build.VERSION_CODES.KITKAT) {
          return orig.commitText(text, newCursorPosition);

      } else {
          // pre-kitkat workaround 
          boolean res = true;
          for (int i = 0; i < text.length(); i++) {
              res = orig.commitText(text.subSequence(i, i+1), newCursorPosition);
          }
          return res;
      }
  }
  ```