# Disabling keyboard for the entire app (Android)

Tags: android, webview, keyboard

I'm using a webView (full screen) which has its own keyboard when needed.
I want to disable the android keyboard popping up every time.

I've tried doing that with `hideSoftInputFromInputMethod(getCurrentFocus().getWindowToken(), 0);` but it doesnt work. Nor does  `android:windowSoftInputMode="stateAlwaysHidden"`
or `getWindow().setSoftInputMode(WindowManager.LayoutParams.SOFT_INPUT_STATE_HIDDEN);`

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Android: Backspace in WebView/BaseInputConnection](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14560344/android-backspace-in-webview-baseinputconnection)

Answer (score 0):

You have to add `android:windowSoftInputMode="stateAlwaysHidden"` for each activity in manifest file. like this example

```
    <activity
        android:name=".MainActivity"
        android:windowSoftInputMode="stateAlwaysHidden" />
```

Comment: As I mentioned in my post - I've tried that. Unfortunately it doesn't help for some reason

Answer (score 0):

Use below function and call it in onTouch() of webview:

```
public static void hideSoftKeyboard(Activity activity) {
    try {
        InputMethodManager inputMethodManager = (InputMethodManager) activity.getSystemService(Activity.INPUT_METHOD_SERVICE);
        inputMethodManager.hideSoftInputFromWindow(activity.getCurrentFocus().getWindowToken(), 0);
    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

}
```

Comment: but I don't have EditText s. all the "edit texts" are of the webview.

Answer (score 0):

Add following code in main(parent) layout in your `layout.xml`

```
android:descendantFocusability="blocksDescendants"
```

Hope it will work. And set following property in your webview

```
android:focusable="false" 
android:focusableInTouchMode="true"



See it:
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools" android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent" android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    android:descendantFocusability="blocksDescendants"
    android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"     tools:context=".MainActivityFragment">

    <WebView
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:focusable="false"
        android:focusableInTouchMode="false">
    </WebView>
</RelativeLayout>
```

Answer (score 0):

```
 if (mActivity.getCurrentFocus() != null) {
            InputMethodManager inputMethodManager = (InputMethodManager) mActivity.getSystemService(mActivity.INPUT_METHOD_SERVICE);
            inputMethodManager.hideSoftInputFromWindow(mActivity.getCurrentFocus().getWindowToken(), 0);
        }
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
<activity          
            android:configChanges="keyboard|keyboardHidden"
            android:windowSoftInputMode="stateAlwaysHidden">
```

Comment: unfortunately no change:/