# Focus on an element with a number input type displays a qwerty keyboard rather than a numeric keyboard

Tags: android, keyboard, android-input-method, android-inputtype

Previously I had a problem to do with soft keyboard backspace on Android 4.4.3 and this only occurs on the device that uses the Android Keyboard (AOSP).

Backspace seems to not work when the view is currently in focus on a text box and when I tap on the right of the entered text in the text box, sometime backspace becomes disabled and you can't get it to work without having to refocus on the text box again.

But I seem to fix the issue by overriding the deleteSurroundingText() in my CustomInputConnection class as suggested in this post ([Android: Backspace in WebView/BaseInputConnection](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14560344/android-backspace-in-webview-baseinputconnection)) However, I discovered a problem which is caused by overriding the onCreateInputConnection method in the WebView, for some reason when putting focus on to an element with an input type set to number, it displays a Qwerty Keyboard rather than a number keyboard.

Any suggestions to why this is happening is much appreciated.

Comment: Is this what your looking for http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4645119/how-to-set-only-numeric-value-for-edittext-in-android?

Comment: No, I don't think so cause the text box I am putting focus to already sets the input type to number. This used to work until I overridden the onCreateInputConnection and return a custom input connection that I created.